# IntelliJ - Ignore generated files with TypeScript

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ 2017.1.3 to develop Angular app. I use TypeScript to write the code and for each `x.ts` file two files are generated `x.js` and `x.js.map`.

The problem is that when I select `x.ts` in the Project panel and click Enter it expand the file to show the two "sub-files" instead of open it in the editor.

Any ideas how to tell IntelliJ to ignore those files?

Answer (score 1):

It's a standard behavior of all tree views in **IntelliJ IDEA**, **WebStorm** and other IDEs. `Enter` on a tree node that has children expands it. `Enter` on a leaf node navigates to the corresponding element. You can use `F4` to open a file.
 I can also suggest switching **Project** tool window to '**Project Files'** view - nesting of generated files inside original one is not enabled in 'scope' modes